# how to create a num question for Moodle with R/exams with partially correct answers

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I want to use R/exams to create randomised Moodle questions. When I create - by hand - a num question in Moodle, I can add partially correct answers, for typical small mistakes, that I grade with 50%. I could not find something like that in R/exams. I can provide some XML of such a Moodle question if that is of any help.

Comment: And I have the same question for schoice questions where I would also like to give partial credits.

Comment: I'm not expert in exams (yet) but did you check `?exams2moodle`? I don't have time check it but I wait the answer :)

Comment: @Matthias Did you try the solution I suggested in my response? If so, please provide some feedback - or simply accept the answer if it worked for you so that it gets flagged as resolved here on SO.

Comment: Yes! It works fine. Thank you very much! That was a crucial question and I am now writing my exam in that way.

Comment: In this case please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left below the vote count. Then the question is flagged as resolved here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Moodle you can use the `verbatim` exercise type (instead of `num` or `schoice` etc.) in a `cloze` exercise. Then you can include the desired Moodle processing directly. For a worked example, see http://www.R-exams.org/templates/confint3/.

Instead of using `num` parts and putting the correct number, say `1.23` into the `exsolution`, you can use `verbatim` parts and then put something like `:NUMERICAL:=1.23:0.1~%50%2.34:0.1#plus feedback text` if `1.23` is fully correct and `2.34` is partially correct. See the Moodle documentation for details:
https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Embedded_Answers_(Cloze)_question_type#Syntax_for_numerical_Cloze_questions