# R exams define a question with a numerical answer with more than one possible correct answers

Tags: r, moodle, r-exams

How can we create a numerical exercise with more than one possible correct answer in the `exams` package?

How does the exshuffle option works? We are trying to shuffle the solutions inside the cloze questions, but in Moodle they never appear shuffled.

Comment: It was not the solution that we were searching for... but if it is the only possible one, let's use it. :)

Comment: If you provide more context for the question, maybe I can provide more guidance or simply say how I would tackle it. As the use cases for R/exams are very heterogeneous it is hard to anticipate what a certain user is looking for.

Comment: Imagine a Wilcoxon paired samples where you admit the exact and the asymptotic p-values as both correct. How would you give 100% do each? 

```
solutions[[2]] <- explanations[[2]] <- round(c(p_value_exact, p_value_asymp), 3)
type[[2]] <- "verbatim"
```

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: In `exams2moodle()` you can do this as a `cloze` with a single `verbatim` item for which you code the `:NUMERICAL:` answer by hand. See the linked answer for details. In other `exams2xyz()` functions this is not directly supported.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It seems tricky since it isn't R code.

Comment: Well, yes and no. The Moodle syntax is unusual but not very complicated. There is a worked example in <http://www.R-exams.org/templates/confint3/>. Try to follow that and if you still have questions follow up with a simple reproducible example. BTW: The R/exams forum on R-Forge is recommended for this kind of discussions that go back and forth. StackOverflow is better for precise questions with precise answers.

Comment: Thank you for being always so diligent, Achim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exams` package has no single `num` question that could have multiple answers. It is doable in `exams2moodle()`, though, in the following way: You make a `cloze` question consisting of a `verbatim` item. And for this you provide the explicit `:NUMERICAL:` code that treats multiple values as fully correct. The strategy is essentially the same as for partially correct answers, except that there are several fully correct answers, see: [how to create a num question for Moodle with R/exams with partially correct answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864404/how-to-create-a-num-question-for-moodle-with-r-exams-with-partially-correct-answ)

Outside of Moodle you could consider alternative ways of asking the question, e.g., via `mchoice` or via `cloze` with several `num` items. For example, if you ask for the prime numbers between 80 and 100, then 83, 89, 97 are correct answers. Either you could provide an `mchoice` list of, say, five numbers and ask: Which of these are prime numbers? Or you could ask three `num` items within a `cloze`: Which is the smallest/medium/largest prime number between 80 and 100?

As for the `exshuffle`: This only pertains to the answer options within `schoice` or `mchoice` questions (either standalone or as sub-questions in a `cloze` exercise). If you need more details, please consider asking another question.