# How to code a question with multiple correct string answers using 'exams' package in R?

Tags: r, package, r-exams

I want to create a question with multiple correct string answers in 'exams' package in R. For example, consider simple Excel-related question. Let's say the following Excel formula is the answer to a question and can be written as a string: "=A2*A3+B2*B3". However, this is not a unique way of writing the formula as there are multiple possible ways of writing the same formula in Excel. For example, the above formula can also be written as "=B2*B3+A2*A3". In latex format, we will leave the empty cell to write the answer with the expression: ~##ANSWER1##~. How can we code this (which accepts both answers as correct) using 'exams' package? I tried to write the code as follows but it does not work.

```
\begin{question}
Write the correct formula.
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l|}
   & A  & B & C              \\ 
1  &    &   &                \\
2  &    &   &                \\
3  &    &   & Enter formula here:  \\
4  &    &   & ~##ANSWER1##~  \\
5  &    &   &                \\
\end{tabular}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}

<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
Answer1 <- c("=A2*A3+B2*B3")
Answer2 <- c("=B2*B3+A2*A3")
soln <- c(Answer1, Answer2)
@    
\begin{answerlist}
\item \Sexpr{soln}
\end{answerlist}

\end{solution}

\exname{multiple correct string answers}
\extype{cloze}
\exsolution{\Sexpr{soln}}
\exclozetype{string}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Achim's suggestions, I corrected the code below:

```
\begin{question}
Write the correct formula.
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l|}
   & A  & B & C              \\ 
1  &    &   &                \\
2  &    &   &                \\
3  &    &   & Enter formula here:  \\
4  &    &   & ~##ANSWER1##~  \\
5  &    &   &                \\
\end{tabular}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}

<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
Answer1 <- c("=A2*A3+B2*B3")
Answer2 <- c("=B2*B3+A2*A3")
soln <- "1:SHORTANSWER:%100%=A2*A3+B2*B3~%100%=B2*B3+A2*A3"
@    
\begin{answerlist}
\item \Sexpr{soln}
\end{answerlist}

\end{solution}

\exname{multiple correct string answers}
\extype{cloze}
\exsolution{\Sexpr{soln}}
\exclozetype{verbatim}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible in `exams2moodle()` and only with `exclozetype` set to `verbatim`. The `string` type can only have a single value. With the `verbatim` type you need to put together the Moodle embedded answer yourself. A worked example is linked in this discussion:

[how to create a num question for Moodle with R/exams with partially correct answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864404/how-to-create-a-num-question-for-moodle-with-r-exams-with-partially-correct-answ)

The example is about a fully correct plus a partially correct answer but the general approach is the same.

Comment: Dear Achim, thank you for your reply and guidance! I changed the code above following your suggestion. I set 'exclozetype' to 'verbatim'. I have only one slot (~##ANSWER1##~) to insert the two correct answers. Would it be correct now if I convert this to Moodle format using 'exams2moodle()' command.

Comment: Yes, one slot is correct. The crucial change is to set up the "exsolution" with the embedded `SHORTANSWER` from Moodle, see: https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Embedded_Answers_(Cloze)_question_type

Comment: Thanks so much @Achim! Now the code is working fine. I edited my original example code above.

Comment: Thanks, Akram, great! To make this more transparent for other readers I would suggest that you change back your question and either modify and accept my answer or post a separate answer and accept that. (Accepting is done by clicking on the check mark below the vote counter on the left of the answers.) Either way is fine for me. The important bit is that the question appears as resolved here on StackOverflow so that other readers can find the solution also.